# Getting technical error after used ruby_desk & ror_desk for odesk API integration.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I am facing problem after follow this documentation:

https://github.com/aseldawy/ror_desk

I'm getting an error with `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :odesk_required

  def odesk_required
    create_odesk_connector
    if !session[:odesk_api_token]
      session[:odesk_back_url] = request.url
      redirect_to @odesk_connector.auth_url
    end
  end

  def create_odesk_connector
    @odesk_connector = RubyDesk::Connector.new(
    OdeskController.odesk_config['api_key'],
    OdeskController.odesk_config['api_secret'], session[:odesk_api_token])
    @odesk_connector.auth_user = session[:odesk_auth_user]
    # Return the created connector
    @odesk_connector
  end

  def reaquire_token
    # Remove any saved tokens
    session[:odesk_api_token] = nil

    # Causes the application to redirect to oDesk and ask for a new token
    odesk_required
  end
end
```

Error : Due to technical difficulties we are unable to process your request. Please try again later. (error: 1)

Please check and reply with your comments on it.

Thanks

Comment: and did you try again later? :)

Comment: It's really hard to figure out how to help you here. Can you give us some more information abut the problem? Maybe a stacktrace? I'm unfamiliar with oDesk - is it a remote service? If so - could it have been experiencing "technical difficulties" and that would be a good reason for an error like what you've observed... is it a service that you need to set up and get running yourself? etc etc... more information about this problem would help because otherwise we're stabbing in the dark.

Comment: hi, i've follow above url for implement ror_desk plugin into my project but the issue is that it will not creating token with before_filter as i checked with logger.debug.

Comment: More information still needed. Please edit your question and add: what you mean about the token. What evidence you have from the logger.debug etc

Comment: Can you please move with this link. right now, I am doing with this and clear all things there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655270/how-can-pass-parameter-with-httparty-gem-after-authentication