# How can pass parameter with httparty gem after authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working for importing odesk API into my local project. for that i used omniauth-odesk gem for authentication and httparty gem for call http request for access odesk information.

in my Gemfile.rb

```
gem 'omniauth-odesk'
gem 'httparty'
```

in odesk_controller.rb

```
class OdeskController < ApplicationController
  include HTTParty

   def user_details
    @odesk_user = env["omniauth.auth"]
   end

   def search_job
    @response = HTTParty.get "http://www.odesk.com/api/profiles/v2/search/jobs.json",   :headers=>{"Authorization"=>"Token token=\"06ede858bcdf8a5fedfa9119fd7074c4\""}
   end

   def check_profile
   end
end
```

in view/odesk/search_job.html.erb

```
<%= @response.inspect %>
```

inspect information are below :

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x3368f40 parsed_response={"server_time"=>1395822483, "error"=>{"status"=>400, "code"=>400, "message"=>"Malformed request: standard autorization is not supported for this API, use an application key"}}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "content-length"=>["155"], "x-odesk-error-code"=>["400"], "x-odesk-error-message"=>["Malformed request: standard autorization is not supported for this API, use an application key"], "expires"=>["Fri, 13 Oct 2000 05:00:00 GMT"], "last-modified"=>["Wed, 26 Mar 2014 08:28:03 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "post-check=0, pre-check=0"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "vary"=>["Cookie,Accept-Encoding"], "date"=>["Wed, 26 Mar 2014 08:28:03 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"]}>
```

I am using correct api key and secret key for odesk API. and token is also correct. but where i am wrong please check and let me know.

I am following below link for making http request

http://developers.odesk.com/w/page/12364012/search%20jobs

thanks

Comment: `{"Authorization"=>"Token token=\` this doesn't look right to me...

Comment: You mean token is not right or format ? I really need this thing going well.

Comment: I am totally guessing... but I'd check the documentation and see if it's really meant to be `{"Authorization" => "Token token='whatever'"}`  or maybe it's meant to be `{"Authorization Token" => "whatever"}`  or even `{"token" => "whatever"}`